# pass in model with request but post form data, not model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

A Razor page is dynamically assembled using model Questionnaire.  Its properties include `List<Question>`, which in turn contains `List<Answer>`.

On form submission, I do not want to bind to the model but want to process the `FormCollection` data to extract answers, some of which is free text, some the IDs that reference Questions and Answers.

It all works fine in MVC4 but in Asp.Net Core 2.2 I get this error:

The model item passed into the `ViewDataDictionary` is of type `<>f__AnonymousType21[System.String]`, but this `ViewDataDictionary` instance requires a model item of type `patientforms.Models.Questionnaire`.
   at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(Object value)`

How do I indicate that I do not want to bind the form data to the model?  As I indicated above, this is not a problem in MVC4 and earlier.

Here is a small portion of the code to process the data but the code does not reach it--I get the InvalidOperationException.

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Ask(IFormCollection coll)
        {
            List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
            p = AppHttpContext.Current.Session.Get<Patient>("_patient") as Patient;
            DateTime.TryParse(p.DateCompleted, out DateTime dtCompleted);

            foreach (var _result in coll)
            {
                if (_result.Key.Contains("Header"))
                {
                    M = Regex.Match(_result.Key, @"(?<=Qn)(?<QuestionId>\d{1,4})(?=Header)");
                    if (M.Groups["QuestionId"].Success)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(M.Groups["QuestionId"].Value, out _questionId);
                        results.Add(new Result { PatientId = p.Id, UserName = p.User, QuestionId = _questionId, QuestionnaireId = _questionnaireId, DateCreated = dtCompleted  });
                    }
                }
                if (_result.Key.Contains("Score"))
                {
                    M = Regex.Match(_result.Key, @"(?<=Qn)(?<QuestionId>\d{1,4})(?=Score)");
                    if (M.Groups["QuestionId"].Success)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(M.Groups["QuestionId"].Value, out _questionId);
                        results.Add(new Result { PatientId = p.Id, UserName = p.User, QuestionId = _questionId, QuestionnaireId = _questionnaireId, DateCreated = dtCompleted });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It seems to be a bit little difficult to reproduce the issue with the existing code , could you share more details or a demo that can reproduce the issue ? If you want to call the method in the controller when submitting the form , you should define the action and controller name, method of form is POST type in @Html.BeginForm  like John said below , and then use `form["fieldName"]` to get the formdata.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in asp and you didn't give me much to work with, but I suggest this:  You should set a controller method to post to specifically, and target that controller method in the form header or by json serialization post of the form.  This would allow you to have a different model to receive the data in.

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("myMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = @item.JobId })){
```

}

Note that you pretty much have to have a target matching model or the route will not go to it.

However, again, the model you post to is not at all related to the model on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my problem was my use of the `asp-for` tag helper to put a few values from the model into hidden fields on the Razor page.  Of course, on submit, it tries to bind those values to a Questionnaire object.  I probably used the tag helper in this way at the start of my work with .Net Core and did not notice it later since the code worked on my development machine and only threw the exception once I published to the server.

Comment: if you're reading a value from the model, it's bound to the model.  You've still got a few options though.  You could move the hidden fields outside the form, exclude them in code-behind from being posted, or post with a json serialization where you specifically pick the fields you want to send.